# CSS, prevent buttons inside a table from resizing

Tags: css

I want the buttons to line up with the numbers. Is therre anyway to make the buttons static or perhaps making the numbers dynamic? I would also appreciate i there´s any best practices when adding CSS to a table because to be honest I mostly just try things out.

**Windowed**:
[image: Windowed]

**Fullscreen**:
[image: FullScreen]

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  padding: 3px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}

.greenButton,
.yellowButton,
.redButton {
  width: 100%; /* set to 100% */
  height: 100%; /* set to 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(82, 202, 126);
  border: solid #cccccc 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888888;
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  font-size: small;
}

.greenButton:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.redButton {
  background-color: rgb(171, 176, 177);
}

.yellowButton {
  background-color: rgb(235, 243, 113);
}

.numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; /* set to 100% */
  height: 20%; /* set to 100% */
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Set the buttons' `width` and `height` css to absolute values. Currently you have them set to `100%`, a value relative to their container, so they would be sized to their container's size.

Comment: yeah I think its the reason  for your problem and you can fix it with absolute value.